# jating: Incorrect number of stars being displayed in case of browser zoom-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jRating](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/) plugin in my web application. The app is working fine in normal conditions but when I **zoom-in (CTRL +) the browser(Chrome) window, an extra star get added at the end**. Here is an example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rickesh_john/XU9LQ/1/).

```
<div class="exemple3" data-average="20" data-id="3"></div>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".exemple3").jRating({
      step:true,
      length : 20, // nb of stars
      decimalLength:0, // number of decimal in the rate
        bigStarsPath: 'http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/jquery/icons/stars.png'  
    });
  });
```

In case of zooming-in the browser window a small star get added, thus increasing the number of stars being displayed. 
I think this css property might be causing the issue:

```
background: url(http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/jquery/icons/stars.png) repeat-x;
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in jRating in general and appears to be caused by rounding.

If I zoom to 125% in Chrome 20 stars take up 560px in width (by measuring with an on-screen ruler) but the div containing the stars is 575px wide. The star image is 23px wide. Scaled, the width of the stars should be `23px * 1.25 = 28.75px` and so take up `28.75px * 20 = 575px` in total. But if 28.75px was scaled down to 28px then the stars would take up `28px * 20 = 560px`.

This doesn't seem to affect Firefox but Safari has the same problem as Chrome.

There's a Chromium bug about this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264863. It's been fixed in WebKit, but only recently (April 2014) and hasn't made it to Chrome yet.

Unfortunately it seems that to workaround this you might have to edit the jRating plugin to use a series of `img` elements instead of a background image. You can try zooming [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XU9LQ/2/) in Chrome to see that that would work.